# php curl requesting twice

Tags: php, api, curl

I have a limit of 25 requests/min from PUBGs official API. For some reason instead of it requesting twice for each search its using up 4 requests. I can't figure out why. I have checked that the code isn't running twice. Only once, but still it's requesting 4 times.

UPDATE:
I tried making a separate page and apparently there is a bug somewhere calling my function twice. Still don't know why but I'm now 99% sure it's not the function itself.

Code For My Request

```
function getProfile($profileName, $region, $seasonDate){
  // Just check if there is an acctual user
  if($profileName === null){
    $data->error = "Player Not Found";
    $data->noUser = true;
    return $data;
  }else{
    $season = "division.bro.official.".$seasonDate;

    /*
      Get The UserID
    */

    $ch = curl_init("https://api.pubg.com/shards/$region/players?filter[playerNames]=$profileName");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer APIKEY',
            'Accept: application/vnd.api+json'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rawData = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    $data->playerId = $rawData["data"][0]["id"];
    curl_close($ch);


    // Testing if user exists
    if($rawData["errors"][0]["title"] === "Not Found"){
      $data->noUser = true;
      $data->error = "Player Not Found";
      return $data;
    }else{

    /*
      Get The acctual stats
    */
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.pubg.com/shards/$region/players/$data->playerId/seasons/$season");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer APIKEY',
            'Accept: application/vnd.api+json'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data->playerDataJSON = curl_exec($ch);
    $data->playerData = json_decode($data->playerDataJSON, true);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
  }
  }
}
```

This is how it's getting called

```
if (isset($_POST['search-username'])) {
  $username = $_POST['search-username'];
  header("Location: /profile/$username/pc-na/2018-01/overall/tpp");
  die();
}
```

In The actual profile php

```
$data = getProfile($page_parts[1], $page_parts[2], $page_parts[3]);
```

Comment: how is getProfile() called?

Comment: I Updated my post

Comment: Your update doesn't show the actual PHP code that calls getProfile(), as @IdontDownVote asked for.

Comment: If you put some echos before/after the curl statements, what is the output? Also, your first if statement does not need an else, as it would return on null otherwise continue with code execution in the function.

Comment: @dossy Yep ur right I'm gonna update this once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after I figure out it's not the function I realized that the culprit was an empty script I was calling. I knew this script created an error which I didn't really care about since it was empty and I had no idea why it was creating the error. For some obscure reason this script created the error. I'll just make a lesson out of it to always fix the smallest errors.

Answer (score 0):

absolutely sure it's only called once? set a lock on it. change it to

```
function getProfile($profileName, $region, $seasonDate){
static $once=true;
if($once!==true){
    throw new \LogicException("tried to run getProfile() twice!");
}
$once=false;
```

Comment: I think this might be a bit of a hack, rather than fixing the cause.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards this won't fix the issue, but it will confirm that OP didn't miss something when he said ```I have checked that the code isn't running twice. Only once,```  - maybe he missed something and it actually is getting called twice? (or more?)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this didn't do anything. I am sure it's only being called once!

Answer (score 0):

I've also been seeing this behavior - a script with a single curl_exec() request gets called twice.
The strange thing is this was *only* happening when running on localhost (under a wampp installation) but when run from any other webserver was fine and it is just called once.

I never managed to debug it completely but it seems to be an issue with the local server so test elsewhere if you are seeing this.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31623799)